# Bootstrap animation every 20 seconds

Tags: jquery, css, animation, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I am using twitter bootstrap in my app. I have a requirement to animate an icon every 20 seconds.

Here is the code i have. Its in coffee script. But its very basic and can easily be related to javascript.

```
@updateCountIndicator = () ->
  data = Math.floor (Math.random() * 10) + 1
  countIndicator = $("#count-indicator")
  countIcon = $("#count-icon")
  countIcon.removeClass("icon-animated-vertical")
  countIndicator.html data
  countIcon.toggleClass "icon-animated-vertical"
  timedCountUpdate()

@timedCountUpdate = () ->
  setTimeout(updateCountIndicator, 20000)
```

The problem is, icon animates the first time(20 seconds after page refresh). But doesn't animate after that. It works properly when i debug using breakpoints. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `setInterval`?

Comment: i didn't use setInterval because i make ajax request in my actual code(changed it to random number here). I want the ajax call to be made only if the previous one was successful. @mu is too short: i will try to get you a demo

Comment: Good call on not using `setInterval` here, mixing `setInterval` and AJAX (or anything else that can take an unknown time or fail) is a recipe for unpleasantness.

Comment: @mu is too short: I created a jsfiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/ExsWP/. This is a simple version of my functionality and i see the same behavior here. The animation happens only after 10 seconds.

Comment: I still don't see the animation repeating every 10s. Didn't know about the CoffeeScript. Thanks for that info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I (finally) see the problem. We'll look at your fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(animateIcon, 20000);
});

function animateIcon() {
    $("#change-color").addClass("animate-color");
    setTimeout(animateIcon, 20000);
}
```

and go from there. Each time `animateIcon` is called, it will:

```
$("#change-color").addClass("animate-color");
```

But that does nothing if `#change-color` already has the `animate-color` class so you only see the `animate-color` animation once. That would lead us to try this CoffeeScript version:

```
animateIcon = ->
    $('#change-color').removeClass('animate-color')
    $('#change-color').addClass('animate-color')
    setTimeout(animateIcon, 20000)
$(animateIcon)
```

That looks like it should re-add the `animate-color` class and re-trigger the CSS animation but it won't. Why not? Well, the second time that `animateIcon` runs, `#change-color` will have `animate-color` at the beginning of the function and it will have `animate-color` at the end when the browser gets control again; since `#change-color`'s classes haven't changed (i.e. it will have the same classes before and after), nothing will happen.

To get around that problem, you need to sort of trick the browser into thinking that the classes have actually changed. One way to get that to happen goes like this:

1. Reset the classes and colors on `#change-color`.
2. Hand control back to the browser.
3. Add `animate-color`.
4. Restart the timer.
5. Hand control back to the browser.

So how do we hand control back to the browser? A `setTimeout(..., 0)` call is a common trick for that. Converting the above to CoffeeScript gives us:

```
addClassAndRestart = ->
    $('#change-color').addClass('animate-color')
    setTimeout(animateIcon, 20000)
animateIcon = ->
    $('#change-color').removeClass('animate-color').css('background', 'transparent')
    setTimeout(addClassAndRestart, 0)
$(animateIcon)
```

The `.css('background', 'transparent')` may or may not be needed but that's what `#change-color` starts with so I added it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/BByJD/

Sorry about the delay, I lost track of this question.